# Windows Update history contradicting itself

Tags: windows-7, updates, windows-update, history

I was just working on a Thinkpad with Windows 7 and in the homepage of `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update` it showed

> Most recent check for updates: Never
>   Updates were installed: Never

but in `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\View update history` it showed a list of updates, only one of which had failed. Why would it say Windows Updates have never happened in one place and in another have a list of updates downloaded?

Comment: Hard to diagnose. Perhaps something in `Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore` (such as DataStore.edb) or `Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs` got corrupted somehow?

Comment: Usually running windows update again will fix that. But to be sure windows update is functioning properly and all files have their valid signature, run a check to see if everything is working as it should be. Hit 'windows key' + 'R'. Then type 'cmd', hit enter. Then in the newly opened dos screen, type 'sfc /scannow'. Hit enter and wait for the results. Did that fix anything?